# \headheight Problem

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm using LuaLaTeX of latest TexLive 2014 on Windows 7.

I want to overlap headers (page numbers) and documents.

My code is as below:

```
\documentclass[a4, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setlength{\headheight}{0mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0mm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thepage{}}

\begin{document}
test1
\clearpage
test2
\end{document}
```

When I typeset the code, 2 pages are generated.
But these layouts are different.
"test1" is above the header line, but "test2" is below.

How can I raise the text after 2nd page?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check the console or the `.log` file, package `fancyhdr` is telling you, what is happening:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (0.0pt): 
 Make it at least 12.0pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Solution: set `\headheight` to `12pt` in the preamble. Manually:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
```

Or if package `geometry` is already used:

```
\usepackage[
  headheight=12pt,
  % other options
]{geometry}
```

BTW: There is a typo (two times) in the MWE: `\0mm` → `0mm`.

Comment: I checked my .log and understood what happened.
I reset \headheight appropriately and \headsep to minus,
and I got a good result.

"\0mm → 0mm."
Sorry, that's my mistake.
My TeX PC was offline, so I [mis]retyped it.
The original code was definitely '0mm'.

Comment: As a beginner, I tried to type something like: \headheight{12pt}. I would like to leave a proper command here for people with the same problem in future: \setlength{\headheight}{12pt}