# Package Fancyhdr Warning@ \headheight is too small

Tags: packages

I am using Oveleaf to compile and it have compile warning. 
When I click on it, it does not show where is my error., only show chapter number

Any advice to how can I check is? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you want the same page style for the whole document so put `\setlength\headheight{26pt}` in the document preamble, presumably where you have other fancyhdr settings.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you have a very long chapter title that is getting wrapped into two lines.  You can use `\chapter[short title]{long title}` to use a shorter title for the header and TOC.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Would it be a problem if I just left it as warming? I just worry, I change the preamble, the whole document went wrong

Comment: It is warning you that your layout is being forcibly changed mid document and will be inconsistent. It only gives that warning when it is true. You can ignore it but don't use the document for publication in that case. As John says the alternative is to use a smaller heading that does fit in the space.

Comment: @aan You can find the solution in the answer to this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198692/headheight-problem